# Upgrade from MS Outlook 2003 to MS Outlook 2013 - how to migrate custom views and menu bars?

Tags: microsoft-office, vba, microsoft-outlook-2013, migration, microsoft-outlook-2003

I'm currently working with `Microsoft Outlook 2003` and want to upgrade to MS Outlook 2013``.

I have made some **modifications** which ware important for my work and I wonder **what is the easiest way to get them into the new `Outlook 2013`**:

- custom views - I'm working with custom views (mainly tables) in e-mails and calendar
- custom menus - I've created 2 additional menus in the menu bar which let me launch makros directly (also with keyboard shortcuts)
- search folders - I'm working with some custom search folders which use custom views and have created some of the above mentioned VBA macros to directly jump to those views with certain keyboard shortcuts

Comment: You would need to recreate these views, menus, and etc. in Outlook 2013.  You will need to make sure the macros still work, and if they use a depreciate function, update them.

Comment: hm, could I at least let VBA print a list of the menu entries with their name and the linked vba macro in my custom menus to facilitate the process of recreating them?

Answer (score 1):

*this is only a partial answer, but I'll extend it if possible*

## Export custom menus in Outlook 2007 via VBA

I made a screenshot of the custom menus to document the status quo in Office 2007.
With the following VBA code, it was at least possible to export the name  and the used macro procedure for each menu entry (print them to the output Window in VBA) which saved me a lot of clicking and copying:

Remark: you have to enter the name of the custom menu, in the below described example, it is called *&Special* .

```
Sub ListMenuItems()
    Dim oCBmnuTools As Office.CommandBarPopup
    Dim oCBmnuSaveMe As Office.CommandBarButton

    Set oCBmnuTools = Application.ActiveExplorer.CommandBars("Menu Bar").Controls("&Special")

Dim i As Integer
For i = 1 To oCBmnuTools.Controls.Count
    With oCBmnuTools.Controls.Item(i)
        Debug.Print .Caption & vbCr & .Parameter & vbCr
    End With
Next i
End Sub
```